# Is it possible to use jquery instead of flash for a certain project

Tags: php, jquery, flash

In this link: http://www.onlinebadplaner.at/ there is a online planer, its made with flash. but I would like to know if that is is possible to be made with jquery only.. any helping sources will be helpful

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Almost anything you can do in flash can be done in javascript/html/css. This answer is way too broad. What have you tried?

Comment: I havent tried nothing yet, I am not really good at javascript

Comment: Probably. Flash would make it compatible in more/older browsers however. You can't do stuff like video with css/javascript on IE 7 for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you're wondering if the functionality can be built at all in jquery. There's very little these days that can be done in flash that cannot be done with javascript. Mein Deutsch ist nicht in übung, but I didn't see anything that was impossible.

No, if you're wondering if there's some easy conversion. The functionality would have to be rewritten from the ground up.